# Output Serialized JSON To String

Tags: php

I have data in this format:

```
[{"name":"Colour","value":"Green"},{"name":"Size","value":"Small"},{"name":"Thickness","value":"Narrow"}]
```

I use this line of code:

```
$decoded_options = json_decode($this->options);
```

To convert it to:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Colour",
    "value": "Green"
  },
  {
    "name": "Size",
    "value": "Small"
  },
  {
    "name": "Thickness",
    "value": "Narrow"
  }
]
```

I have then tried to loop over in various ways to output it (i.e):

```
$output = '';

foreach($decoded_options as $key => $value) {
    $output += (string) $value;
}

return $output;
```

None of my attempts have been successful. I wish to output the data in this format as a string:

```
name: Colour
value: Green

name: Size
value: Small

name: Thickness
value: Narrow
```

How would this be achieved?

Comment: In PHP, `.` is used for concatenating strings, not `+`. So it should be: `$output .= (string) $value;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something below

Also replace `+=` by `.=` because `+=` will work in **js** not in **php** string.

```
$json = '[{"name":"Colour","value":"Green"},{"name":"Size","value":"Small"},{"name":"Thickness","value":"Narrow"}]';

$decoded_options = json_decode($json);



$output = '';

foreach($decoded_options as $key => $value) {

    $output .= 'name:  '. $value->name;
     $output .= PHP_EOL;
    $output .= 'value:  '. $value->value . PHP_EOL. PHP_EOL;
}

echo  $output;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I have added second `foreach` which will give me the advantage to handle any number of elements in a single array.

```
$str = '[{"name":"Colour","value":"Green"},{"name":"Size","value":"Small"},{"name":"Thickness","value":"Narrow"}]
';

$dataArray = json_decode($str, true);
$outputString = "";
foreach($dataArray as $data) {
    foreach($data as $key => $element) {
        $outputString .= $key.": ".$element.PHP_EOL;
    }
    $outputString .= PHP_EOL;
}
echo $outputString;
```

[Demo link](https://3v4l.org/4vpfv)

Answer (score 1):

First of all use `true` as second parameter in `json_decode` to make sure you are getting an array back:

```
$decoded_options = json_decode($this->options, true);
```

Then simply look through, minding keys and create the string:

```
$output = '';

foreach($decoded_options as $value) {
    $output .= "name: {$value['name']} \n";
    $output .= "value: {$value['value']} \n\n";
}

return $output;
```

If you want to generalize it so that you don't hardcode `name` and `value` but use whatever comes as key, you can do so like this:

```
$output = '';

foreach($decoded_options as $value) {
    foreach ($value as $key => $v) {
        $output .= "$key: $v \n";
    }
    $output .= "\n";
}

return $output;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$json = '[{"name":"Colour","value":"Green"},{"name":"Size","value":"Small"},{"name":"Thickness","value":"Narrow"}]';

$decoded_options = json_decode( $json );

$output = '';

foreach($decoded_options as $key => $value) {
    $output .= (string) $value->name;
    $output .= (string) $value->value;
}

echo $output;
```